# Bookmarks not being copied

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, bookmarks

Before you ask, yes I have read another SO article, plus an article by Bruno Lowagie the creator of iText, on how to do this.  The fact remains that I cannot get it to work.  Tracing the execution through eclipse makes it *look* like it's working, but no bookmarks actually get copied using this code.

I'm probably missing something really stupid and ask that someone point me the right way:

```
void resize (String pdfIn, String pdfOut, float x, float y, float scale) {
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
List <HashMap <String, Object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark ( reader ) ;
// landscape letter:
Document doc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(792, 612), 0, 0, 0, 0);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(pdfOut));
doc.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
    doc.newPage();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    // page rescaling, mandatory:
    cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
}
writer.setOutlines ( bookmarks ) ;
doc.close();
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really very sure about this,but

write this line

```
List <HashMap <String, Object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark ( reader ) ;
```

After

```
doc.open();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it.  The doc object pertains to the writer, not the reader.  But I checked anyway to no avail.

Comment: But you have open the doc first to read the content, So see where you open the doc for reading

Comment: You open the doc for writing, not reading.  I checked your proposed solution just in case, but it did not work.

Comment: You're using `PdfWriter` instead of `PdfCopy` and maybe your bookmarks use named destinations. Have you tried the example from chapter 7? http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141 What doesn't work? Did you check if the links are using named destinations?

Comment: Before I generated this post I actually did go through the chapter 7 example.  I did at one point replace PdfWriter with PdfCopy, to no avail.  When I say "it doesn't work", I mean that when the PDF is copied, scaling is accomplished as the main purpose of my code, but no bookmarks are present in the new document.

Comment: If I cannot figure this out quickly, would you be amenable to consulting with us for a short engagement?  I'd like to reach out to you directly to see if we can come to a business arrangement.